# Trouble setting Bridged network connection in VM VirtualBox Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to set up a Bridge network connection on VM VirtualBox Linux on my Windows 10 PC. My PC is connected to the network via an ethernet cable and I would like the VirtualBox to use that network too.

I tried multiple things, attached are the screenshots of current settings. What should I do from here?

EDIT: I am also unsure if I even need a bridged connection. The only purpose I need internet is for usual tasks such as surfing the web.

[image: configuration screenshot]

Comment: For "usual tasks such as surfing the web" you better use a NAT.

Comment: Regardless, if you want the bridge problem solved, you should better describe the actual result that you expect but can't achieve.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right network adapter selected from the Name dropdown? Seeing as you already have bridges, you may want to bridge to the Hyper-V bridge and not the physical interface itself. I'm not sure if Hyper-V is trying to exclusively own the physical interface.